# Laravel , como configurar los archivos css y js

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, webpack, blade, gulp

tengo un proyecto con laravel y tengo configurado el siguiente fichero para webpack, pero luego en mi template uso un archivo "head.blade.php" donde cargo todos los vendors, uso jquery, boostrap, moment...etc

Cuando subo esto y paso alguna prueba de rendimiento en google page speed o en otros servicios me dice que tengo más de 20 JS que los comprima, y no se como hacerlo.

**Fichero webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.scripts([
    'resources/js/app.js',
    'resources/js/bootstrap.js'
], 'public/js/app.js').extract([
], 'public/js/vendors.js').version();

mix.scripts([
    'resources/js/cars.js',
], 'public/js/cars.js').extract([
], 'public/js/vendors.js').version();

mix.scripts([
    'resources/js/customers.js',
], 'public/js/customers.js').extract([
], 'public/js/vendors.js').version();

mix.js('resources/js/bootstrap-table-es-ES.js', 'public/js');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

**Head.blade.php**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

<meta content="" name="descriptison">
<meta content="" name="keywords">


<!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
<link href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css')  }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css')  }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/remixicon/remixicon.css')  }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css')  }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Template Main CSS File -->
<link href="{{ asset('assets/css/style.css')  }}" rel="stylesheet">

{{--JQUERY--}}
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js') }}"></script>

{{--BOOTSTRAP-TABLES--}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/boostrap-tables/bootstrap-table.min.css')  }}">
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/boostrap-tables/bootstrap-table.min.js')  }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/boostrap-tables/bootstrap-table-es-ES.min.js')  }}"></script>

<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/popper/popper.min.js')  }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')  }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/bootstrap-table-es-ES.js') }}"></script>


<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/moment/moment.min.js') }}"></script>

<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/diets.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/routines.js') }}"></script>
```

Gracias,

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas usando incorrectamente la lógica de Laravel Mix.
Referencia de documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#running-mix

Dentro de tu carpeta de proyecto ejecuta lo siguiente:

```
npm install
```

Después para ejecutar el mix

```
// Ejecuta todas las tareas de mix...
npm run dev

// Ejecuta todas las tareas y las minifica...
npm run production
```

El "MIX" sirve para compliar todos los archivos de JS y de CSS en un solo documento que luego referenciarás en tu documento usando el ayudante "asset". Ej:

```
<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/scripts.js')}}"></script>
```

Después de compilar, Laravel Mix coloca esos archivos en tu carpeta public de forma automática para que puedas acceder facilmente usando los helpers.